# Intellij doesn't show documentation in mouse hover

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am using IntelliJ 14 and I told the IDE to show me the documentation on mouse hover but this is all I get (for OutputStreamWriter in my case):

[image: IntelliJ documentation]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried looking in settings? There are several options for documentation handling there.

Comment: JDK is set? caches up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to File->Settings->Editor->General->Other and check Show quick documentation on mouse move.
That should do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: For me File->Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion->Show the documentation popup (in ###ms) .. but this too didn't work for me

Comment: it was some internal IDE corrupted state; i re-cloned the project from github and documentation started showin

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I hover over `OutputStreamWriter` and hit ctrl-Q.

I can only think, either:

- your JDK is not set on the project
- your JDK is not a full JDK (try downloading and installing latest, check `JAVA_HOME`
- caches are not built (try invalidate caches and restart intellij.

Hope this helps, since it should work. (I am on v14.0.3)